# Connect pods via service name in GCP K8's

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I have a number of Services running against Pods hosted within a cluster on Google Cloud K8's.

**Service 1** is an Ingress - `basic-ingress`

**Service 2** is a NodeJS API Gateway w/ 2 Pods - `security-gateway-svc`

**Service 3** is a NodeJS API w/ 2 Pods - `some-random-api-svc`

and so on service 4 / 5 / 6 etc....

My Ingress allows me to access exposed services via a sub domain however I would like to move my external API's behind my Gateway so I can handle auth etc in the gateway.

What I'd like to do is allow `security-gateway-svc` to connect to `some-random-api-svc` without having to go via dns or outside of my cluster.

I figured I could update my ingress so all sub domains use the same service entry and allow the Gateway to figure out where the traffic should go.

I can configure this just fine locally as everything runs on `localhost` and I specify a `port` so it's fairly straight forward.

Is it possible however to expose pods to other pods within a cluster via the service name instead of an actual domain / dns look up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You service should be accessible within your cluster via the service name.

Point your gateway entry for each api to the service name.

Something like `http://some-random-api-svc` should work.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to make pods reachable within your kubernetes clulster is to use services [link to services documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). For this you need to create a yaml block that will create an internal hostname binded by an endpoint to your pod. In addition, a selector will allow you to bind one or multiple pods to that internal hostname. Here is an example:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: $YOUR_SERVICE_NAME
  namespace: $YOUR_NAMESPACE
  labels:
    app: $YOUR_SERVICE_NAME
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "8000"
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: $YOUR_SERVICE_NAME

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: $YOUR_SERVICE_NAME
  namespace: $YOUR_NAMESPACE
  labels:
    app: $YOUR_SERVICE_NAME
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: $YOUR_SERVICE_NAME
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: k2m
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: $YOUR_SERVICE_NAME
          image: alpine:latest
      restartPolicy: Always
```

Finally, use the service name in your ingress controller route to redirect traffic to your api-gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes uses CoreDNS to perform in-cluster DNS resolution. By default, all `Service`s are assigned DNS names in the (FQDN) form of `<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`. So your `security-gateway-svc` will be able to forward requests to `some-random-api-svc` via `some-random-api-svc.<namespace>`, without routing the traffic outside of Kubernetes. Keep in mind that you shouldn't be interacting with pods directly, because pods are ephemeral; always go through `Service`s.